# Pandas change background column color

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

im tryna change the color background for the column names, like in this script "case its changing the row1 column1 color, but the problem its that its changing also the column name for all the sheets in "False"

```
workbook = xlwriter.book
        cell_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'fg_color': '#00FFFF',
            'border': 1})
        ws.write(0,0,False,cell_format)
```

[image]

ANEX: ENTIRE SCRIPT

```
import pandas as pd
from timestampdirectory import createdir
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter

import os
import time


def svnanalysis():
    dest = createdir()
    dfSvnUsers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnUsers.xlsx"))
    dfSvnUsers.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)
    dfSvnGroupMembership = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnGroupMembership.xlsx"))
    dfSvnRepoGroupAccess = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnRepoGroupAccess.xlsx"))
    dfsvnReposSize = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "svnReposSize.xlsx"))
    dfsvnRepoLastChangeDate = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "svnRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx"))
    dfUserDetails = pd.read_excel(r"D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\CM_UsersDetails.xlsx")
    dfUserDetails.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)

    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-")
    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(dest, f'{timestr}Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx'))

    dfUserDetails.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='UserDetails', index=False)
    dfSvnUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnUsers', index=False)
    dfSvnGroupMembership.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnGroupMembership', index=False)
    dfSvnRepoGroupAccess.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnRepoGroupAccess', index=False)
    dfsvnReposSize.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='svnReposSize', index=False)
    dfsvnRepoLastChangeDate.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='svnRepoLastChangeDate', index=False)



    for column in dfSvnUsers:
        column_width = max(dfSvnUsers[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = dfSvnUsers.columns.get_loc(column)
        xlwriter.sheets['SvnUsers'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['UserDetails'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['SvnGroupMembership'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['SvnRepoGroupAccess'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['svnReposSize'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['svnRepoLastChangeDate'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)

    for sheet_name in xlwriter.sheets:
        ws = xlwriter.sheets[sheet_name]
        ws.freeze_panes(1, 0)

        #workbook = xlwriter.book
        #cell_format = workbook.add_format({
         #   'bold': True,
          #  'fg_color': '#00FFFF',
           # 'border': 1})
        #ws.write(0,0,False,cell_format)

        #for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        #worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
        #cell_format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
        #cell_format.set_bg_color('blue')
        #ws.write(0, 0,'test',cell_format)

    xlwriter.close()
```

This is the full script that i use to add more xlsx files as sheets on at only 1 excel

Comment: It would be helpful if you upload full code. For example, It is not clear what `ws` is.

Comment: @Park, sorry, i edited the post and i added the entire code, the #lines below are also some tries to make that change color background for column name

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me can you please elaborate further???